# CSS class wild card with :not

Tags: css, wildcard

I am using  `[class*='-text']` selector for text color classes with variables
The whole rule look like:

```
[class*='-text']{
    --textcolor:inherit ;
    --textalpha: 1;
    color: rgba(var(--textcolor),var(--textalpha)) !important;
}
.red-text{--textcolor: 244,67,54}
.red-text.text-lighter-1{--textcolor: 239,83,80}
.purple-text{--textcolor: 156,39,176}
.purple-text.text-lighter-1{--textcolor: 171,71,188}
.blue-text{--textcolor: 33,150,243}
.blue-text.text-lighter-1{--textcolor: 66,165,245}
.text-alpha-2{--textalpha: 0.2}
.text-alpha-4{--textalpha: 0.4}
.text-alpha-6{--textalpha: 0.6}
.text-alpha-8{--textalpha: 0.8}
```

Now when I want to exclude some bootstrap classes like `.align-text-top` or `.align-text-bottom` I am using selector as

```
[class*='-text']:not(.align-text-top):not(.align-text-bottom)
```

But this totally cancel the wildcard rules. Any advice how to exclude those classes from whildcard rule?
Thanks

Comment: are you sure the color declarion is good, I am pretty sure it won't work like this ... you cannot use inherit as value of rgba

Comment: the selector is fine https://jsfiddle.net/7cnm9uhf/1/ so the issue is the color as I said, it's wrong

Comment: Also after your edit, you can't use `inherit` inside the `rgba()` function

Comment: As @ItayGanor and others have said your `color` declaration is wrong.

Comment: That inherit might be wrong but it anyway picks color declared for body tag if no additional class is added like red-text which has .red-text{--textcolor: 244,67,54}

Answer (score -1):

## Explanation/Advice:

- With CSS Variables you should declare global variables in the `:root` pseudo-class
  <sub>Source: [MDN - Using CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)</sub>

---

- The first `<span>` rule is targeting all CSS that contains `"align-text"` with the `*=` attribute selector.
- The second `<span>` rule is targeting all CSS that contains `"align-text"` with the `*=` attribute selector, excluding ones that end specifically with `"-top"` and `"-bottom"` with the `$=` attribute selector.
  <sub>Source: [CSS Tricks - The Skinny on CSS Attribute Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)</sub>

---

```css
:root {
  --textcolor: 255, 0, 0;
  --textalpha: .5;
}
span[class*="align-text"] {
  color: rgb(var(--textcolor));
}
span[class*="align-text"]:not([class$="-top"]):not([class$="-bottom"]) {
  color: rgba(var(--textcolor),var(--textalpha));
};
```

```html
<span class="align-text-middle">
  text
</span>
<span class="align-text-top">
  text
</span>
<span class="align-text-bottom">
  text
</span>
```

Comment: My answer no longer reflects OP's original question, but at the time did answer the initial question.